# Do these questions all imply the same thing?

Tags: c++, string

I came across a question- "Find the shortest substring with maximum distinct characters"
Is this question same as "Find longest substring with all distinct characters?" and "Find the longest non repeating characters substring?"

If yes can anyone help me with the algo for this? I have searched online but all of them are getting implemented via different logics on the internet

My question is not based on the english but if logically all these questions would give the same output for all possible strings.

Comment: English is ambiguous; those might mean the same thing or might not. Examples could clarify.

Comment: The shortest substring with maximum distinct characters could potentially have repetitions, so no that is not the same as a substring with all distinct characters, or non-repeating.

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming the second question is actually the _longest_ substring with all distinct characters, otherwise a simple algorithm would be to simply return the first character of the string.

Comment: Despite the focus on substrings, I think this is more appropriate for [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can someone explain the difference between distinct and non repeating? I was sure that this is the same.

Comment: Suppose I have a string "abdab" then will the output for all 3 questions will be abd?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: This is an English question. "maximum distinct characters" means some characters do not need to be distinct. Just find the pattern containing the **most** distinct characters. However "all distinct" and "non repeating" are different. They mean the same thing as each other and there is no room for duplicates.

Comment: @Galik "maximum distinct character" would include all characters right? Can you demonstrate with an example the difference between the 2?

Comment: You say that this question is not based on english, but it is.   The interpretation of the english expression in each case means the required output is different.

Answer (score 0):

> **”** Find the shortest substring with maximum distinct characters

In “The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog” all characters in the English alphabet are present. So that's the maximum distinct characters for this string, the 26 characters A through Z. The question asks for the shortest substring that has all these characters *somewhere*, maybe with some characters occurring two times or more. Since G is only present at the end that means the substring must end there. Where it starts, well, it's not at the start, since the T is repeated.

For handing in a solution one should perhaps state up front an assumption that “character” is used in the common English meaning where uppercase and lowercase versions are regarded as the same character.

This then requires uppercasing or lowercasing functionality, which the C++ standard library only supports for the BMP subset of Unicode (because the most general functionality is via [`towupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towupper) or `towlower`, and while `wchar_t` is some Unicode encoding on all extant systems I know of, it's only 16 bits in Windows).

---

> **”** Find longest substring with all distinct characters

Here “all distinct characters” means that the substring must not contain the same character twice or more.

---

> **”** Find the longest non repeating characters substring

The most meaningful interpretation to me here is that “repeating” refers to having the same character in *successive positions* in the substring, e.g. `"jeep"`. Having the same character occurring twice or more but in non-successive positions, like `"yay"`, is not repeating. In this interpretation. The question could be clarified with examples.

Comment: In the first question you said " with some characters occurring two times or more" but it needs to *distinct* characters so there can't be any repetition right?

Comment: Disregarding the uppercase/lowercase issue, the distinct characters in a string are what you get after putting all the characters in a `std::set`.